# Adding an event handler to a coffeescript class for jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am a coffeescript newbee want to use multiple jquery sliders on one clientside view. I want to use the slide event for several functions. The slider displays, the value is shown at start, the slider is usable, but the event is not used.

```
class Slider  
 constructor: (@min, @max, @value, @id) ->
   d3.select(@id).attr("style", "width: 500px; margin: 15px;")
   @myslider = $(@id).slider
     min: @min
     max: @max
     value: @value
   $(@id).bind
  slide: @slideme

 slideme: (event, ui) =>
   $(@id +"_data").val(@value)

$(document).ready ->
  slider1 = new Slider(0,800,100,'#testslider')
  $("#testslider_data").val($("#testslider").slider("value"))
```

What do I need to do have the value of the slide shown in the html when using the slider?

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is off. This:

```
 $(@id).bind
slide: @slideme
```

should be this:

```
$(@id).bind
  slide: @slideme
```

or:

```
$(@id).bind slide: @slideme
```

or my personal favorite:

```
$(@id).bind(slide: @slideme)
```

CoffeeScript is very sensitive to whitespace and formatting, your formatting defines most of your code's structure so you **must** be careful and consistent; you're mixing one and two spaces for you indentation, that will cause nothing but trouble.

Your original code:

```
constructor: (@min, @max, @value, @id) ->
  #...
  $(@id).bind
 slide: @slideme
```

will be seen like this:

```
constructor: (@min, @max, @value, @id) ->
  #...
  $(@id).bind

slide: @slideme
```

So your `slide: @slideme` argument that is intended for `bind` will look like another property for the class and it will end up as this JavaScript:

```
Slider.prototype.slide = Slider.slideme;
```

Paste your code into the **TRY COFFEESCRIPT** panel at [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/) and you'll see what it thinks your CoffeeScript means.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast feedback. The indentation was off, but more through pasting in it here than in the original. The '$(@id).bind(slide: @slideme)' now leads to this error: _TypeError: this.id is not a function_, so the slider does not update the value.

Comment: What is `@id` inside `slideme`? Are you sure that function looks like `$(@id + "_data").val(@value)` and not `$(@id "_data").val(@value)`?

Comment: The right answer is '"#{@id}_data"' for the problem, since I wanted to combine the strings. The data is now updated. My code looks now like this:    '  slideme: (event, ui) =>
    @value=@myslider.slider("value")
    $("#{@id}_data").val(@value)' where the value is updated before it is send to the datafield. Thanks for the hints - @mu is too short